# Showing that not every pair of points in a two sheet hyperboloid can be joined by a curve - solution verification & feedback

Tags: calculus, geometry, multivariable-calculus, proof-explanation, solution-verification

I'm working through *Multivariable Mathematics by Shifrin* currently on chapter 2 and I've encountered the following question:

[image]

I've done the first part and got that $X$ is a hyperboloid of one sheet and $Y$ is a hyperboloid of two sheets. The difficulty I've had is in coming up with a solution for part b). This is the thought process I've had up to this point:

Looking at the hyperboloid of two sheets you see there is a disconnect between two sets of points. In a previous question the idea of collinearity was used. So I thought to apply it here. To test out the idea I found two points one in the top sheet and one in the bottom sheet. After some algebra I defined:
$A = (0,\sqrt{3},2)$ to be the top sheet point and $B = (0,\sqrt{3},-2)$ to be the bottom sheet point (i.e $A \in X$ and $B \in Y$).

The idea of collinearity states that two points are collinear if there exists a scalar, call it $\lambda$ such that $\lambda A = B$. In this specific case that would mean:

$$\lambda (0,\sqrt{3},2) = (0,\sqrt{3},-2)$$

Where $|x| \leq \sqrt{3}$

I chose to solve this system in a matrix form:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
\sqrt{3} & \sqrt{3} \\
2 & -2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\text{using row reduction for good measure we arrive at:}\ 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 \\
0 & -4 \\
\end{bmatrix} 
$$

Which implies that there does not exist a solution. Now I attempted to extend this idea to a general case of:

$$
\lambda\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
\pm \sqrt{(z^{2}-1)-x^{2}} \\
\pm \sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}+1}  \\
\end{bmatrix} 
=
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
\pm \sqrt{(z^{2}-1)-x^{2}} \\
\pm \sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}+1}  \\
\end{bmatrix} 
$$

Whereby if I choose the 2nd components to have the same sign , the 3rd component on each side to have opposite signs and restrict $|x| \leq \sqrt{z^{2}-1}$, I'll have the sort of conditions to establish what I want. So that would give me a set up of:

$$
\lambda\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
 \sqrt{(z^{2}-1)-x^{2}} \\
 \sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}+1}  \\
\end{bmatrix} 
=
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
 \sqrt{(z^{2}-1)-x^{2}} \\
- \sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}+1}  \\
\end{bmatrix} 
$$

My questions are the following:

1. If my presentation is right, how do I treat the argument in the general case? Here it is easy to see that the 3rd component is different but that is only "talking" about it. I haven't really argued it rigourously.
2. I feel there is an easier argument to the one I'm attempting to present what would it be if it is the case?
3. Just to confirm the understanding of collinear, if this wasn't a straight line would the same idea stand about collinearity? i.e instead of a "line" as a straight line the line could be any type of curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collinearity only applies to straight lines, so there's a problem with your argument.  However, a much easier argument is available.  There are no points on the two-sheeted hyperbola with $z=0$.  You have found a point on the surface with $z>0$ and also one with $z<0$.  Argue that by the intermediate value theorem, any curve connecting these points must pass through $z=0$ and therefore cannot lie entirely on the surface.

Comment: I see the overall argument. To make sure I'm organizing it correctly: I would have to state it in two dimensions right? If I let $x = 0$. Then if a curve passed through the above points that would mean by IVT there is point where $z = 0$, this means $y^{2} + 1 = 0 \rightarrow y = \pm 1$. How would I conclude it?

Comment: Now thinking about it, I don't need to go through all that, but I do need to state some sort of continuous curve I believe?]

Comment: @dc3rd Yes.  A curve in $3$-space can be viewed at a function $f(t)=(\xi(t),\eta(t),\zeta(t))$ with $0\leq t\leq1$, and $\xi,\eta,\zeta$ are continuous.  All that matters hete is $\zeta$. We have $\zeta(0)>0,\ \zeta(1)>0$ so but the intermediate value theorem there is a $0<c<1$ with $\zeta(c)=0$.

Comment: Hi @saulspatz. I was wondering if the following sketch would work as an argument. So based off your idea, I also got a direction vector from the two points I found $v = (0,0,4)$. Using this direction vector I could form the following parametric equation: $f(t) = (0,\sqrt{3},-2) +t(0,0,4)$. Now looking at the third component this would be a continuous function between $(-2,2)$, so by IVT there must exist a $t$ such that $f_{3}(t) = 0$, now I did find a $t$ for the line ($t=1/2$), but what would I have to specifically say to apply it to my hyperboloid to make it thorough?

Comment: The problem with taking a specific line segment is that there's no reason to believe it lies on the hyperboloid.  You could apply the very same argument to a one-sheeted hyperboloid.  You have to do this for a general, and therefore unknown, curve.

Comment: Ah, I see. So I think my issue here is the "discomfort" I feel in not being able to explicitly state a curve that the idea could apply to. (or at least me finding one)

Comment: It's something lots of people have a bit of trouble adjusting to.  In order to prove that something can't be none, it's no good showing examples that don't work.  You've got to prove that no example can work.  Usually, you do this by assuming you have a working example, and deducing something absurd.  In this case, we proved that there's a point with $z=0$ on the surface, when we know there is no such point.

Comment: I do get that we are using the contradiction method, but where did we explicitly show that there was no $z = 0$ on the surface? ...apologies if I'm going on.

Comment: Well, I didn't write that, but you know it already.  The equation of the surface is $x^2+y^2-z^2=-1$, so if $z=0$ ...

Comment: Negative square root in $\mathbb{R}$.......which is a no no. Now I may be going beyond my pay grade at this moment, but this wouldn't be the case in a space such as $\mathbb{C}^{2}$ would it?....also Thank you for your extra help

Comment: Yes, that's right, but you're beyond my pay grade too.  I don't know anything at all about complex functions of several variables.

Comment: Well we'll keep on learning and reconvene here in a year or two then....take it easy